# Mark a not-ready object for garbage/finalizing having reference(s)

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have a `l:Map<Long,Foo>` of foo objects. And in my application context I create instances of `Foo` too much, some instances are shared with more than one thread stack.
The `Foo` class

```
class Foo{
 public long id;
 public AtomicInteger ins;
 public Foo(long d,AtomicInteger i){id=d;ins=i;}
 public Foo(long d){id=d;ins=new AtomicInteger(1);}
}
//--
class Bar{
 Foo friend;
 public Bar(Foo f){friend=f;}
 //....some other properties
}
```

Here is the method for getting a `Foo`

```
public synchronized Bar a_bar_please(long id){
 Foo f=l.get(id);//no null allowed, Map implementation doesn't allow it
 if(f==null){f=new Foo();l.put(id,f);}
 else{f.ins.incrementAndGet();}
 return new Bar(f);
}
```

And here is a method for removing a bar

```
public synchronized void a_gone_bar(Bar b){
 if(b.friend.decrementAndget()==0){l.remove(b.friend.id);}
}
```

I remove(ready for GC) the `Foo` instance when there is no any `Bar` instances.
There are no any problem with the current situation if everything goes normal.

---

**Case Study:**
Now Assume 10 threads call for `a_bar_please(id:long):Bar` method with id 1, so it means 10 new `Bar` Object which all of the instance have a shared `Foo` instance references with `friend field`.
So here the `Foo` instance has 11 references, 10 from `Bar` instances and one from the context `l:Map`.
Now I like to remove the `Foo` instance from the map `l` when there is no ant `Bar` instances associated with.
Considering 8 of threads holding a `Bar` plus it's shared `friend:Foo` object don't call `a_gone_bar(b:Bar):void`, so the context will hold the `Foo` object because the minimum number of `ins` will be 8, and context will never remove it for marking for GC.
So here how may I mark the `Foo` instance when there is a reference from the map?

Answer (score 0):

Check out `WeakRefernece` class. Sounds like that is what you need.
In a nutshell, you store `new WeakReference(foo)` in your context, rather than just `foo`, and modify your `.get` accordingly (`ref = context.get(id); foo = ref == null ? null : ref.get`).
You can also override the `.enqueue` method on it to remove the entry from context when it gets collected.

Basically, the idea is that GC considers objects, that are only weakly-referenced, unused, and will collect them during its next cycle.

This will also eliminate the need for your own reference counting (`a_gone_bar()`), the GC will take care about removing the bars from context for you.